# getting error in both postman and angular

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

I have an angular front end and back end is in .net. I am getting an error when I trying to call the post method in .net side. I tried to call that same method in Postman and got the error. Not sure what am I doing wrong. below is my post method in .net:

```
 [HttpPost()]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AllItProjectsList>> PostAllItProjectsList(AllItProjectsList allItProjectsList)
        {
            _context.AllItProjectsList.Add(allItProjectsList);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetAllItProjectsList", new { id = allItProjectsList.ProjectId }, allItProjectsList);
        }
```

when I call this method from angular, I get the below error:

Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'projectId', line 1, position 437."

Below is the screen shot:

[image]

when I tried to call below URL in postman:

```
https://localhost:44328/api/AllItProjectsLists?Name=Test&Description=TestDec
```

I get the error saying ReferenceError: Name is not defined

Below is the screen shot:

[image]

allitprjectlists is defined in my model class. Below is the definition:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{

```
  public partial class AllItProjectsList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string SubType { get; set; }
        public string ExecutiveSponsor { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string AppDev { get; set; }
        public double? AppDevPriority { get; set; }
        public double? AppDevEffort { get; set; }
        public string ProjectRequestDate { get; set; }
        public string ProjectApprovalDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpectedCompletionDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ActualCompletionDate { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string SurveyId { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My call from angular to .net is below:

```
 AddProjectDetails(project: AllItProject) {
     const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
     return this.http.post<AllItProject>(ROOT_URL , project, httpOptions);
}
```

None of the fields are required except ProjectId . ProjectId is the identity field in the database. I am not sure why angular is complaining that projectId is null and postman is throwing an name reference error.

below is the value of the project object:

[image]

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you check what is the value for the project object(from  return this.http.post<AllItProject>(ROOT_URL , project, httpOptions);
}) when you send the request.

Comment: I put the picture of the project object above. It has some extra fields, but they are all defined in my model class. The project ID in project object is empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as soon as I put the Observable in front of this method

```
AddProjectDetails(project: AllItProject): Observable<AllItProject>
```

code started working.